# Can I access zookeeper from AWS Elastic Mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-zookeeper, elastic-map-reduce, emr

I'm new to Hadoop, and running under AWS Elastic Mapreduce.

I need cluster-wide atomic counters in Hadoop and was suggested to use zookeeper for this.

I believe zookeeper is part of the Hadoop stack (right?), how would I access it from an Elastic Mapreduce job in order to set and update a cluster-wide counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe zookeeper is part of the Hadoop stack (right?)

[ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) (ZK) is not part of the Hadoop Stack. It's a Top Level Project (TLP) under Apache and is independent of Hadoop. So, first ZK has to be installed on EC2. Here are the [instructions](http://pulasthisupun.blogspot.in/2012/08/setting-up-zookeeper-quorum-on-amazon.html) for the same.

> how would I access it from an Elastic Mapreduce job in order to set and update a cluster-wide counter?

Once installed ZK can be used to generate a cluster wide counter using the ZK API. Here ([1](http://www.mail-archive.com/zookeeper-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg01976.html) and [2](http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/Sequence-Number-Generation-With-Zookeeper-td5378618.html)) discussions on the approach with the pros and cons. Here are some other [alternatives](http://srinathsview.blogspot.in/2012/04/generating-distributed-sequence-number.html) for ZK for the same requirements.

Comment: This answer is incorrect in the context of the question. As an element of the Hadoop stack deployed within AWS EMR, Zookeeper is indeed a part.

Answer (score 0):

You can, as Praveen Sripati answers.
But I wan't to clarify some points:

1. Keep in mind, that zk has a limited write rate (~300 request per
   second)
2. Clients can see stale data (zk don't guarantee read consistency across replicas).

I suggest to use dedicated sequence generator server, which will generate sequences for you (and this service can use Zk or whatever it wants). One example of such service: https://github.com/kasabi/H1